# Use a Common Class in several different classes

Tags: html, css, containers

Im kinda confused about some div and tags usages. I know I can chain two classes with `.class1.class2`, that I can use `.class1 h1` to select all h1 elements with `class1` class, that `p.class1` selects p elements with a class of `class1` but I wanna use a class like `button` and use it in different div but I don't know how to differentiate in the CSS code.

```css
.header {
  height: 222px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.container h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>jane bloglife</h1>
        <h2>Welcome to the world of Jane's world</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="front-image">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Jane's</h1>
      <h2>Fashion Blog</h2>
      <div class="button"> <a href="">suscribe</a></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want to differentiate the elements with a `container` class that is inside the `header` class from the other `container` class that is inside the `front-image` class

Answer (score 1):

To style elements inside `header`, use this format `.header > .container`:

```css
.header>.container h1 {
  font-size: 50;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>jane bloglife</h1>
    <h2>Welcome to the world of Jane's world</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="front-image">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Jane's</h1>
    <h2>Fashion Blog</h2>
    <div class="button"> <a href="">suscribe</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To style elements inside `front-image`, use this format `.front-image > .container`:

```css
.front-image>.container h1 {
  font-size: 50;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>jane bloglife</h1>
    <h2>Welcome to the world of Jane's world</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="front-image">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Jane's</h1>
    <h2>Fashion Blog</h2>
    <div class="button"> <a href="">suscribe</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```